# How can a CSS id style be accessed in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery and cannot find out how to add a CSS id to a page element.

For example, here are the inline CSS stlyes:

```
#main h2 {
background: url(open.png) no-repeat 0% 10%;
padding-left: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
}
#main h2.close {
background-image: url(close.png);
}
#main h2.highlight {
color: red;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

and here is the jquery I attempted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("h2").addClass('#main h2.highlight');
```

It works of course with classes but I cannot figure out how to get the styles onto the h2 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a limp here, but:

```
$('#main h2').addClass('highlight');
```

Will add the `highlight` class to `<h2>` elements *within* (descendants of) the element with ID `main`, **effectively making the `<h2>` element(s) match the rule `#main h2.highlight`.** Is that the objective? If not, please ignore.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the class "highlight" to the h2 tags you could do it like this:

```
$("h2").addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: 'main' has to be the id of some ancestor of h2 and not the h2 itself  for this CSS to work: `#main h2.highlight { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$("h2").addClass('#main h2.highlight');
```

to:

```
$("h2").addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: _highlight_ is not a CSS class in my document, it is an id. I am trying to reference that `#main h2.highlight` id

Comment: @jonshariat In the CSS you posted, `highlight` is a class not an id. If it was an id it would be `#highlight` (or `h2#highlight`).

Comment: @jonshariat: If "highlight" is not a class in your document then it should be. It is referenced in your CSS as a class. Besides, every DOM node can only have one ID and every ID can only be used for one DOM node so IDs are not suitable for things like highlighting. Classes don't have those restrictions. Every node can have many classes and every class can be used with many elements.

Comment: @Laxman13 It's not *wrong* per se. It's just unnecessary (and hence, considered bad practice by some) since IDs are, per definition, unique. This renders the element selector `h2` superfluous (and there is no guarantee that the mechanism parsing the selector will use the highly efficient `getElementByID()` method directly). I'm not saying that there will *never* be a reason to use the `element#ID` style selector, just pointing out that if you catch yourself doing it, you should probably step back and take a second look on the problem :)

Comment: @jensgram +1 Ok, I was thinking it may just be a bad practice type thing, but it will definitely make me rethink my selectors, thanks for explanation:)

Answer (score 1):

Use css selectors `.` for class and `#` for id in jQuery function `$('(css-selector)(name)')` for selecting.

```
$("h2").addClass('highlight');
```

This will select `h2` element and add class `highlight` to `h2` element

You cannot add assign `id` to elements (only to one element), since `id` is supposed to be unique. If you have only one `h2` element then

1. First select `h2` with `$('h2')`
2. Assign attribute with `attr` function `$('h2').attr('id','someid')`. However it is not recommended.